# filter out the records which are matched in a file in shell

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

I have a file text.txt with the records below:

```
xyz[4.3],default,
harry[1.0],default, 
molly[1.1],default, 
abc[1.0],rome, 
abc[1.1],rome, 
abc[1.2],rome, 
abc[1.4],rome,
abc[2.1],default, 
abc[2.2],default,  
ghi[1.0],moon, 
ghi[1.1-Test],moon, 
def[3.9],default,
def[4.2],default,
```

now i will input a record name as a variable based on that variable those records should be filtered out to new file

ex:
for the above text.txt file if i input abc,rome as a variable the outputfile.txt should have only the following records:

```
abc[1.0],rome, 
abc[1.1],rome, 
abc[1.2],rome, 
abc[1.4],rome,
```

i have tried:

```
final_order=$(awk -F/ -v RS=',|\n' \
  'FNR==NR{a[$1] = (a[$1])? a[$1] "," $0 : $0 ; next}
  {s = (s)? s "," a[$1] : a[$1]}
  END{print s}' ./temp/test.txt ./temp/variable)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using awk you can do:

```
awk -v s='abc,rome' 'BEGIN{sub(/,/, "[^,]*&", s)} $0 ~ s' test.txt
abc[1.0],rome,
abc[1.1],rome,
abc[1.2],rome,
abc[1.4],rome,
```

`sub(/,/, "[^,]*&", s)` will convert search term `abc,rome` into `abc[^,]*,rome`.

Comment: hi anubhav,how can we write the o/p into a file and also what if i have only abc as search term instead of abc,rome how can re-write that awk statement

Comment: For just `abc` as search term use: `awk -v s='abc' 'BEGIN{sub(/,/, "[^,]*&", s)} $0 ~ s' test.txt > output.txt` where `> output.txt` is used for redirecting output to a file.

Answer (score 1):

Using parameter expansion in bash to create a regular expressions for grep:

```
search=abc,rome
grep "^${search/,/\[[^]]*\],}" text.txt
```

The expansion replaces comma with `\[[^]]*\],` which matches `[`, than anything up to `]`, `]` itself, and the comma.

Answer (score 1):

In this case I think the most simple is:

> awk '/,rome/' file
>   abc[1.0],rome,
>   abc[1.1],rome,
>   abc[1.2],rome,
>   abc[1.4],rome,